# Split string every 80 characters in PHP

Tags: php, string

I'm pulling data from a mainframe.  I have this long string.  I need to make a print view of this string.  If I split it every 80 characters it will format correctly (since that's how it's chopped up on the mainframe screen).  By splitting I mean inserting an end of line or a break in the view.

The code is simple:

```
$string = "A big long string that needs to be chopped every 80 chars";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
chunk_split ( $string, 80 );
```

There's a 3rd parameter, used to set the separator. By default, this is a platform-specific end-of-line.

This is probably faster than `wordwrap` since it doesn't take care of words at all.

Comment: If not faster, certainly closer to what is actually meant.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [wordwrap](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function.

Answer (score 2):

Use `wordwrap()`:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

```
wordwrap($string, 80, "\n", true);
```

Substitute `<br>` for `\n` depending on your needs.